# Get list of distinct stores objects grouped by categories - django

Tags: django, django-models

This is how my models look like:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=255)
    is_valid = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    default_link = models.TextField(default="")
    store_url = models.TextField(default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class StoreCategory(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

I want to get lists of Store objects grouped by categories. so for example this is the data in StoreCategory:

```
store | category    | sub_category
-----------------------------------
ABC   | Electronics | Laptops
ABC   | Electronics | Mobile Phones
PQR   | Food        | Food
PQR   | Fashion     | Men
XYZ   | Electronics | Laptops
```

The output should be something like this:

```
{
    'Electronics': [ABC, XYZ],
    'Fashion' : [PQR],
    'Food': [PQR]
}
```

here `[ABC, XYZ]` are Store objects and not just their names.

Answer (score 0):

From what you provide, I think you should use a `ManyToManyField` rather than a `ForeignKey`. That being said:

```
def get_stores_by_cat():
    result = {}
    for sc in StoreCategory.objects.all():
        result[sc] = []
        for s in sc.store.all():
            result[sc].append(s)

    return result
```

or more concisely using list comprehension (it's more a "dict" comprehension in this case):

```
stores_by_cat = { sc: list(sc.store.all()) for sc in StoreCategory.objects.all() }
```